# How to place the extracted values from one file into another

Tags: tcl

The following are the extracted elements from a file

```
Mg1.qna o a vss vss n 0.36 0.03 mult=4 $$UNI

Mg1.qpa o a vcc vcc p 0.36 0.03 mult=6 $$UNI
```

Now the above elements are to be replaced into another file that contains the following

```
set name(A) qp18

set source(A) vccgated_1p24

set drain(A) vldoout

set gate(A) pgtbias

set bulk(A) vccgated_1p24

set inst(A) 1

set name(B) qp2

set source(B) vccgated_1p24

set drain(B) vccgated_1p24

set gate(B) vccgated_1p24

set bulk(B) vccgated_1p24

set inst(B) 1

set bulk(B) vccgated_1p24
```

Can I use regsub to replace each items one by one?

else if indexing used could that be handy?

Comment: How do the 10 fields from your "extracted elements" map onto the 6 arrays?

Comment: You've posted almost this identical question like a dozen times.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the file you are importing is describing transistors, or some other electronic component etched on to a silicon chip. It seems like the file format is space separated. Here is a suggestion, but you need to clarify this much more.

```
set inputFile [open INPUT_FILE_NAME_GOES_HERE]
set outputFile [open OUTPUT_FILE_NAME_GOES_HERE w]
set lineNumber 0
while {[gets $inputFile line] >= 0} {
    set items [split $line]
    # assumes you have at most 8 lines for components A through H in your file
    set letter [lindex {A B C D E F G H} $lineNumber]
    puts $outputFile "set name($letter) [lindex $items 0]"
    puts $outputFile "set source($letter) [lindex $items 1]"
    # as many more puts commands as you need for all the columns
}
close $inputFile
close $outputFile
```

Comment: @ Joseph Bui : what are A B C D E F G H..... am gettin error that these should be of type int......

Comment: Sorry, I reversed the arguments. {A B C D E F G H} should come before the $lineNumber (fixed in the answer).